# How to set up an alert when Liveness/Readiness probe fails in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, alert, prometheus

I am trying to set up alerts/monitors for my Kubernetes PODs where my application is deployed.

I am using **Kubernetes=1.15**.

I am trying to set up alert for following two scenarios:

1. When any POD goes down due to some reason, alert should get triggered.
2. When my application goes down on any of the POD, alert should get triggered.

For (1) I am setting up an alert if Liveness probe failed >= 1, if all you care about is one or more pods going down

For (2), I am setting up an alert on Readiness probe_type and result as failed >= 1

For (1), I am using **kubelet:prober_probe_total{probe_type=Readiness,result=failed,..}**

For (2), I am using **kubelet:prober_probe_total{probe_type=Liveness,result=failed,..}**

Reference:

1. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/prober/prober_manager.go
2. https://godoc.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/prober

I have been thinking that an alert should get triggered when I get any non zero value for them. But even when everything is fine, I am getting non-zero data.

So I am clueless here.

Comment: are you using prometheus alert manager?

Comment: yes I am using prometheus.

Comment: You can configure prometheus and alert-manager for this purpose, and can add webhooks into the configMap of alert manager. 

Channels in application like slack can be used and the alerts triggered during the crashLoopBackoff like situation gets pushed.